# AopAlliance (Guice): Call another method from an intercepted method

Tags: java, aop, guice, aopalliance

In method interception with AopAlliance is there a way to call a method from the class who's method was intercepted?

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
     public void interceptMe() {}
     public void invokeMe() {}
}
```

and

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
     public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
          // This is where MyClass.interceptMe() is intercepted
          // I would like to call MyClass.invokeMe() for the instance of the class who's method was intercepted
     }
}
```

I will be happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
((MyClass)invocation.getThis()).invokeMe()
```

http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/doc/org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation.html